# APNS production won't work

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I created two certificates. One for Development which works just fine, and the other one for production.
I switched the `Product->Edit Scheme` into Ad Hoc, also downloaded Ad Hoc mobileProvision from the member center from Apple's.
I used [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) tutorial to get all these things done, and as said, the development version works perfectly.

**prod_cert.pem** and **prod_ck.pem** were concatenated into **prod_ck.pem**

I am using the `simplePush.php` example to test APNS. Had to change:

**APNS SERVER SIDE**

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

to:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

**CERTIFICATE**

as well as the local cert (production):

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'Push/dev_ck.pem');
```

into:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'Push/prod_ck.pem');
```

I am thinking maybe something is wrong with the binary? I tested the production  certificate in front of the APNS, using:

**`openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert prod_cert.pem -key prod_key.pem -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer`**

and it goes through fine. 
I am somehow not getting the notification to the distribution app. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
$pem = dirname(__FILE__) .'/'.'ck.pem';
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195',$err,$errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

Comment: As mentioned, the tutorial shows the complete php file, I just thought to highlight the relevant parts